# Картинка выходит за пределы своего блока при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему картинка выходит за пределы своего блока при наведении. Нужно, чтобы картинка не вырезалась с помощью `overflow: hidden`, а увеличивалась в своём блоке.

Пример кода:

```css
.post {
  flex: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.post__img img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.post__img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <div class="post__img">
    <img src="img/300x150-4.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Что вы конкретно хотите?

Comment: Чтобы при наведении на картинку она увеличивалась но не выходила из своего блока

Answer (score 2):

```css
.post {
  flex: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.post__img{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.post__img img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.post__img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<article class="post">
  <div class="post__img">
    <img src="https://www.granneman.com/files/cache/b2db80143ee1dd79e8d21b90ae364d2e.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</article>`
```

Comment: "Нужно, чтобы картинка не вырезалась с помощью overflow: hidden", вот здесь если честно я не понял что вы имели ввиду. С overflow прекрасно срабатывает